# Having problems aligning a button inside a form (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I´ve been doing a school project and I'm having problems making a button align to the right.

I'm using bootstrap for this HTML project.

Image of the current aspect of the button:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9I28.jpg)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  
  <button
    class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
    type="button"
    id="dropdownMenuButton"
    data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true"
    aria-expanded="false">Dropdown button</button>
    
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck3">Option 3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <button class="btn btn-dark me-5 mx-2 ml-auto" type="submit">Login</button>
  
  </form> <!-- this is closing a form that wasn't opened anywhere -->
  
</div>
```

Comment: I put your code into a snippet without touching anything but just better formatting it and adding a comment about the form tag being closed but never opened and adding the boostrap asset

Comment: The buttons, in the photo you provided, are inside a "card". Then the card is aligned to the right, not the buttons. What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code
i added "d-flex justify-content-between" class main div that has class "dropdown"

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown d-flex justify-content-between">
  
  <button
    class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
    type="button"
    id="dropdownMenuButton"
    data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true"
    aria-expanded="false">Dropdown button</button>
    
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck3">Option 3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <button class="btn btn-dark me-5 mx-2 ml-auto" type="submit">Login</button>
  
  </form> <!-- this is closing a form that wasn't opened anywhere -->
  
</div>
```